# Agregar propiedad que muestra el último elemento a la clase Array

Tags: javascript, prototipos

Tengo un array con varios valores, y quiero obtener el último valor. Normalmente hago `a.slice(-1)[0]`, pero para simplificar esto agregué un prototipo a la clase *Array*, que es una función llamada `último`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  Array.prototype,"último",{
    value: function(){return this.slice(-1)[0]}
  }
)

var a = [2,3,1]
console.log(a.último())
```

Luego estuve mirando que para obtener la longitud del array no es mediante una función, sino que es una propiedad. Entonces se me ocurrió hacer que `último` sea una propiedad en vez de una función, pero no sé hacerlo.

En pocas palabras, sería hacer que en vez de un método sea una propiedad. Esto me sirve para no tener que usar los paréntesis.

¿Es posible hacer esto? De ser así, ¿Cómo se haría?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código está bien, solo hay que cambiar `value` por `get`.

Lo siguiente hace que al acceder a la propiedad `último` del array , ejecute la función que muestra el último elemento y muestre el valor de retorno.

Para esto, se está agregando está agregando la propiedad `último` del prototipo de la clase *Array*.

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  Array.prototype,"último",{
    get: function(){return this.slice(-1)[0]}
  }
)

var a = [2,3,1]
console.log(a.último)
```